# Slightly different answers obtained for solution to differential equation by using separation of variables and integrating factor

Tags: calculus, ordinary-differential-equations

By using separation of variables I get

$\frac{dy}{dt} = -ay + 2 $

Multiply across by dt

$ dy = -ay dt + 2 dt$

Then divide across by y

$ \frac{1}{y}dy = -a dt + \frac{2}{y}dt$

Rewriting

$ \frac{1}{y}dy = (\frac{2-ay}{y})dt$

Then divide across by $\frac{y}{2-ay}$

$ \frac{1}{2-ay}dy = dt$

This is not a standard intergral so let $ u = 2-ay $ theefore $\frac{du}{dy} = -a $ and $ dy = \frac{du}{-a} $

$\frac{1}{-a} \int \frac{1}{u}du = \int dt $

$\frac{1}{-a} ln(2-ay) + C_1 = t + C_2$

Multiply across by -a

$ ln(2-ay) + -aC_1 = -at + aC_2$

As we are dealing with a constant shift which can be anywhere we can write

$ ln(2-ay) = -at + C_3$

Raise both sides to the power or e

$ e^{ln(2-ay)} = e^{ -at + C_3}$

$ 2-ay =e ^{ -at + C_3}$

$2-ay = e ^{ -at} e ^{C_3} $

$2-ay = C_4 e ^{ -at}$

$ y = \frac{ C_4 e ^{ -at}-2}{-a}$

$\frac{ C_4 e ^{ -at}-2}{-a}$ is the same as $\frac{ -C_4 e ^{ -at}+2}{a}$ - We are multiplying by -1 above and below

Therefore

$ y = \frac{2- C_4 e ^{ -at}}{a}$

By using an Integrating factor I get

$\frac{dy}{dt} = -ay + 2 $

Add ay to both sides

$\frac{dy}{dt} + ay = 2 $

Obtaining the integrating factor

$I = e^{\int a dt} = e^{at}$

Multiply across by the the integrating factor gives

$\frac{dy}{dt} e^{at} + aye^{at} = 2e^{at} $

We know from the product ruls that $\frac{dy}{dt} e^{at} + aye^{at} = \frac{d}{dt} ye^{at}$

$\frac{d}{dt} ye^{at} = 2e^{at}$

Integrate both sides gives

$ ye^{at} = 2 \int e^{at}   $

$ ye^{at} = 2 [\frac{e^{at} }{a} + C_1] $

We can rewrite this as:

$ ye^{at} =  \frac{2e^{at}+C_2 }{a} $

Divide across by $e^{at}$

$ y =  \frac{2+\frac{C_2}{ e^{at}}}{a} $

Therefore

$ y =  \frac{2+ C_2 e^{-at}}{a} $

There is a difference in sign between the two answers

Comment: Welcome ; you said :"we are dealing with a constant shift which can be anywhere "; so $-C_4=C_2$, with $C_2=-C_4$. Right ?

Comment: A constant is a constant...set $-C_1=A$

Comment: Thanks to everyone. I looked at an easier differential equation and attempted to solve it both ways.. 
$\frac{dy}{dt} = -ay $. 
Again the signs are reversed in the solution but the value of one constant is the negative of the other so the value of y always ends up the same. Thanks